# Numerically solve delay ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, ecology

I am trying to numerically solve a simple delay ODE in mma for the first time. I think this is likely a simple fix.

I first tried to solve system as ordinary differential equation system for up to =l. And then use these solutions as history functions for the delay differential equation system. I keep getting the error: NDSolve::dvnoarg The function na appears with no arguments

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
c = 200; Q = 4; P = 1.92*10^-6; ea = 2.6*10^-6; ga = 
6.24*10^-8; l = 0.5; ba = 98; pr = 0.2;
sol0 = NDSolve[{
 r'[t] == pr (c - r[t]) - P r[t]/(Q + r[t]) (na[t] + ma[t]),
 na'[t] == P r[t]/(ea (Q + r[t])) na[t] - pr na[t] - ga 
 na[t] p[t],
 ma'[t] == ga na[t] p[t] - pr ma[t],
 p'[t] == -pr p[t] - p[t] ga na[t] ,
 r[0] == 1000, ma[0] == 0, na[0] == 100, p[0] == 1000},
 {r, na, ma, p}, {t, 0, l}][[1]];

sol = NDSolve[{
 r'[t] == pr (c - r[t]) - P r[t]/(Q + r[t]) (na[t] + ma[t]),
 na'[t] == P r[t]/(ea (Q + r[t])) na[t] - pr na[t] - ga 
 na[t] p[t],
 ma'[t] == ga na[t] p[t] - pr ma[t] - 
   Exp[-pr l] ga na[t - l] p[t - l],
 p'[t] == ba Exp[-pr l] ga na[t - l] p[t - l] - pr p[t] - 
   p[t] ga na[t] ,
 r[0] == 1000, na[t /; t <= l] == sol0[[2]], ma[0] == 0, 
 p[t /; t <= l] == sol0[[4]]},
{r, na, ma, p}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You might look at `sol0[[2]]` and `sol0[[4]]`.  You probably want `(na[t] /. sol0)`, or to use `NDSolveValue` for `sol0` (the first `NDSolve` call).

Comment: Thanks, (na[t] /. sol0) worked.

Comment: BTW, what's the model?  Looks like a nutrient-consumer-virus system.

Comment: You are correct @Chris K

Comment: Nice, pretty close to my own research.  I added an "ecology" tag.  Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure the separate `NDSolve` to initialize the initial conditions is even necessary. If you just use your second `NDSolve` with the initial conditions of the first, it gives a warning `NDSolve::ihist` but seems to run:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
  r'[t] == pr (c - r[t]) - P r[t]/(Q + r[t]) (na[t] + ma[t]), 
  na'[t] == P r[t]/(ea (Q + r[t])) na[t] - pr na[t] - ga na[t] p[t], 
  ma'[t] == ga na[t] p[t] - pr ma[t] - Exp[-pr l] ga na[t - l] p[t - l], 
  p'[t] ==  ba Exp[-pr l] ga na[t - l] p[t - l] - pr p[t] - p[t] ga na[t], 
  r[0] == 1000, na[0] == 100, ma[0] == 0, p[0] == 1000},
  {r, na, ma, p}, {t, 0, 400}, AccuracyGoal -> 128][[1]];

LogPlot[Evaluate[{na[t], ma[t], p[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 400}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However note that I had to really crank up `AccuracyGoal` due to the very low levels that `na[t]` reaches.  Maybe other parameter values would be less violent.